# Get form data from HTTP post

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Normally, I need to fill in 'email' and 'password' to login a website. But I found out there is another field  '-_-' when I am looking through the browser's developer tools. And the value of that field is always changing every time I login. Is there any way to get that value from Selenium or any others module.

Currently, I wrote the script by using Selenium. But I want to change to request module. In order to do that I need to know the value of that unknown field.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Can you share the URL? The DOM?

Comment: Hi, here is screen shoot https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpd7qef0cx23ust/Screenshot%20from%202017-12-21%2011-55-36.png?dl=0. Could you check it out. Thanks

Comment: This does not help much as it is impossible to see where this element is located in respect to the other elements higher in the hierarchy

Comment: Here is DOM of email and password filling in two different picture . https://www.dropbox.com/s/bx8c63hja1m412z/1.png?dl=0     https://www.dropbox.com/s/nl53jo8hsdi5img/2.png?dl=0  Thanks

Comment: So value of what element are you trying to get?

Comment: I tried to get '-_-' that I marked with ? icon in the second diagram. It wasn't given by me. It added in post form by itself. Any clue? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161664/discussion-between-eugene-s-and-moorejohn90).

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the following css selector and then getting an attribute:

```
values = []
value = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='hidden']:nth-child(1)")
print value.get_attribute('value')
```